# HTML Dropdown menu in nav

Tags: html, menu, dropdown

I made a nav bar which has some tabs, but I want to make a dropdown menu which appears on hover in genre tab. Code goes like this:

```
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">PLaying Now</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Genre</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

And the css code is:

```
nav { /* Navbar align */
  text-align:center;
}

ul { /* Navbar settings */
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li { /* Text align */
  float: left;
}

li a { /* Menu variable */
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 16px;   /* height width */
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) { /* Tab over mouse */
  background-color: #111;
}

.active { /* Tab active color */
  background-color: #791519;
}
```

What do I must change to make that happen?

Comment: Have a read through this. It is pretty simple to implement: 
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but when I tried to make it work with my code I had some problems. That's why I asked. I wondered if someone could help me with the code I already have.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Links you need at Genre
  `<li><a href="index.html">Genre</a></li>`

```
<li><a href="index.html">Genre</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

and then add to your CSS

```
ul ul { display: none; }
ul li:hover ul { display: block; }
```

Comment: I tried that, it is good but not good enough, because the menu bar is getting more height instead of a new menu appearing.

Comment: Then you should use Javascript/jQuery open up an external Menu on hover or click.

Answer (score 0):

Here, combined the W3Schools tutorial with your code.

W3Schools Tutorial Link: [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp)

**CSS**

```
nav { /* Navbar align */
        text-align:center;
    }

    ul { /* Navbar settings */
        display: inline-block;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    li { /* Text align */
        float: left;
    }

    li a { /* Menu variable */
        display: block;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 16px 16px;   /* height width */
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover:not(.active) { /* Tab over mouse */
        background-color: #111;
    }

    .active { /* Tab active color */
        background-color: #791519;
    }

    /* DROPDOWN */
    li.dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Playing Now</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="index.html" class="dropbtn">Genre</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul></nav>
```

Comment: yeah, I made myself those fixes, but when the dropdown menu is appearing, the whole nav bar is getting more height so the dropdown menu can appear.

Comment: cause I want the dropdown menu to be relative so it can appear on top of some images I have below.

Comment: Right, here's an image of the two navs side to side: [link](https://s18.postimg.org/5mln9t9cp/image.png) 

If your nav changes height, it is not from the code I provided you with. Debug your code a bit. If you're still having issues later on, ask another question, but define it better.